# How to compare counted elements?

Tags: sql, oracle

I don't know how to compare counted elements inside of **ist and osv** columns.

```
select 
  r.parent_id
, count(case when c.config_field_id=100 then c.key_value end) as ist
, count(case when c.config_field_id=101 then c.key_value end) as osv 
from relation as r 
left join config_value_number as c 
  on r.child_id = c.key_value 
where c.config_field_id in(100, 101) 
  and r.relation_type_id in(200, 201) 
group by parent_id
```

Result:

| Parent_id | ist | osv |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 3 | 3 |
| 501 | 2 | 2 |
| 502 | **5** | **1** |

So here above I have to compare whether **ist** column and **osv** column values are same or not. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need same value like this right ?

Comment: In Oracle, `AS` between the table identifier and alias is syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
select * from (
select r.parent_id, 
count(case when c.config_field_id=100 then c.key_value end) as ist, 
count(case when c.config_field_id=101 then c.key_value end) as osv 
from relation as r 
left join config_value_number as c on r.child_id = c.key_value 
where c.config_field_id in(100, 101) 
and r.relation_type_id in(200, 201) 
group by parent_id
)a
where ist=osv
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, that worked. But how can I compare if there will be 3 columns

Comment: @IslombekNematov `WHERE col1 = col2 AND col2 = col3`

Comment: In Oracle, `AS` between the table identifier and alias is syntactically invalid.

Comment: @MT0 is optional thing if you don't use that's fine but if you use it it is also fine. it's depended syntax you use.

Comment: @PiyushKachhadiya **NO**, in Oracle it is syntactically invalid to use it. In other RDBMS it may be optional but in Oracle it is forbidden. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=50403589ffbe98f6e2f8cbe688364aa5)

Comment: @MT0 , oh you says in table alias and I am say column alias. I know it but i replay same query because, I don't know witch version use of user asking. that's why i give him same query.  it's say it's work.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the standard predicate on an aggregation result: `HAVING`:

```
select 
  r.parent_id
, count(case when c.config_field_id=100 then c.key_value end) as ist
, count(case when c.config_field_id=101 then c.key_value end) as osv 
from relation as r 
left join config_value_number as c 
  on r.child_id = c.key_value 
where c.config_field_id in(100, 101) 
  and r.relation_type_id in(200, 201) 
group by parent_id
HAVING count(case when c.config_field_id=100 then c.key_value end)
     = count(case when c.config_field_id=101 then c.key_value end)
;
```

You don't even have to include the CASE expressions in the SELECT list - you can just evaluate them in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: In Oracle, `AS` between the table identifier and alias is syntactically invalid. Also, regarding your footnote, if the OP wants to output the counts in the `SELECT` clause then they do want the `CASE` expressions there otherwise they will display a count of something different.

Comment: Yeah it also worked correctly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The trivial solution is to treat your current query as a table expression of a main query. Then, it's easy to perform the comparison.

For example:

```
select x.*,
  case when ist = osv then 'same' else 'diff' end as are_equal
from (
  -- your existing query here
) x
```